# How to inject Tags around matches?

Tags: php, html, insert, replace

```
$pattern = "/of/i";
$text = "Offspring offers OFFENSIVE Offerings";
```

I want to make all "of"s bold, but keep the Case. Would I use a replace-function I would override the original part (of, Of, oF and OF will be of). So, how to "inject" the  Bold-Tags around of all matches instead of replacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use back-reference in the replacement string (`$0` means use the text that matches the whole pattern). The case will be preserved.

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/of/i', '<b>$0</b>', $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just use a preg_replace with a capture:

```
$pattern = '/(of)/i';
$text = "Offspring offers OFFENSIVE Offerings";
$replace = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>' . $1 . '</b>', $text);
```